# Laravel 4: Auto assign controller

Tags: php, laravel-4

In my route, I have a bunch of this:

```
Route::resource('nerd', 'NerdController');
Route::resource('cool', 'CoolController');
Route::resource('my', 'MyController');
Route::resource('soso', 'SosoController');
```

How is it possible to merge it into one? For example, if my URL is http://mydomain.com/autoroute/abc/create, then it will automatically go to AbcController and call create function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$routeModelControllers = [
    "nerd",
    "cool",
    "my",
    "soso",
];

foreach($routeModelControllers as $route) {
    Route::resource($route, ucfirst($route) . 'Controller');
}
```